# Razor Editor crash VS 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, crash, editor

Everything worked fine, but for some reason from today whenever I try to open .cshtml files with Razor Editor VS 2010 IDE crashes. i  tried uninstalling MVC 3/4/ Web pages 1/2 but it didn't help. I am currently editing the files in HTML editor. I don't want to reinstall VS itself. Please suggest

Comment: We're going to need more information in order to help you here. Does it crash with a specific error, have you checked the event log for the information or attached a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: That's how it is with MS products. Install, set up, reinstall :-)

Why don't you want to reinstall?

Comment: reinstalling means a lot of time.(@JaredPar) it just crashes. No message. for one or two times it showed:an unhandled win32 exception in devenenv.exe [11572].

Comment: @easternwind try looking in the event log. It should have at least the exception which is causing the crash.

Comment: should i post the log file here. It is big around 262 KB

Comment: I have uploaded to mediafire. http://www.mediafire.com/?us4s4i8w4kk910s

Comment: <entry>
    <record>312</record>
    <time>2012/01/08 21:12:38.939</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Unexpected system error mode before loading package [Visual Web Developer HTML Source Editor Package]</description>
    <guid>{BFCC0C3C-6F87-4285-A6C8-BB616061800D}</guid>
  </entry>

Comment: Anyway I fixed it up by reinstalling visual studio